# Java: Threads depending on files

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering what is going wrong with the following code and if anybody could help me. What I`m trying to do is:

- Creating a folder with some .txt-files in it
- Creating a thread for each .txt-file included in that folder
- Preforming a task for each thread (in this particular case just waiting for some seconds)
- And afterwards after the tasks are preformed, deleting the file the individual thread depends on.

My problem is that every time i run the code, merrily every thing works fine, exept of deleting all files after preforming the tasks. The result is that only one .txt-file was deleted and the others are still in that folder. :/

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Julien :D

```
public abstract class Threads {
static Formatter x;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    //create folder with 10 .txt-files
    File theFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\");
    theFolder.mkdir();

    for(int files = 0; files <= 10; files++) {
        x = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\"+files+".txt");
    } 

    System.out.println("Created the folder and files");
    //Close the formatter
    x.close();


    //Start a thread for each file in that folder
    System.out.println(Files.list(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\")).count());
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[(int) Files.list(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\")).count()];

    for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        int del = i;
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    //after timeout of ones thread, terminate file
                    File theFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\"+del+".txt");
                    theFile.delete(); 
                    System.out.println("deleted file: "+del);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
        threads[i].start(); System.out.println("Started thread no. "+i);}       

    System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the files are called "C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\0.txt" [etc]...?  You could read the names of the files dynamically.

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Have you tried stepping through it?

Comment: Have you checked if the threads are Daemons?

Answer (score 6):

You only close one formatter (the last one), therefore all other files still have open handles and can't be deleted. Try this:

```
 for(int files = 0; files <= 10; files++) {
     x = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\TheFolder\\"+files+".txt");
     x.close();
 } 
 //x.close(); <-- this will only close the last formatter that is assigned to "x" after the loop is done
```

Comment: In this case he may be able to delete only that file which was created at last ? Isn't it ?

Comment: Wow, thanks. I hadnt expected the solution to be that easy.

Comment: Yes, as all other file handles were open, only the last file could be deleted. You would have noticed actually, when examining __boolean successful = theFile.delete();__, as it would be __false__ for all other files except the last one.